# How electric field can be less than force per unit test charge?

Tags: electric-fields

I have been going through some physics objective questions and struck with this one
Q:A negatively charged metallic ball is supported on a rigid insulating stand. We wish to measure the electric field E at a point P in the same horizontal level as that of the metallic ball. To do so, we put a positive charge q and measure F/q. The electric field at the point P is
 
a) =F/q 
b) <(F/q) 
c) >(F/q) 
d) none of these.
Guess what?. I chose (a) and its wrong. (b) is correct. I am squeezing my brain. How can that be correct.? Please give detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field strength is only $F/Q$ if the test charge is infinitesimally small so it cannot affect the metal ball.

For example, suppose the metal ball is uncharged in which case the fortce should be zero. A positive charge will polarise the ball and create an attractive force even though the charge on the ball is zero. In the case of a charged ball the positive charge will polarise the ball and increase the atttractive force.

Comment: If the magnitude of the test charge is infinitesimally small, won't the electric field be infinity?

Comment: No, it just means the force on the charge will be infinitesimally small. All we are doing is taking the limit of $F/Q$ as $Q \rightarrow 0$, i.e. basically calculating $dF/dQ$. The ratio remains non-zero even as $Q$ and $F$ both tend to zero.

Comment: Thank you!. What happens for electric field when both metallic ball and charge q are positive?

Comment: @Nandhakishore: would you like to speculate, given the discussion in my answer?

Comment: I will. But please tell me the case when both the metallic ball and the charge is positive.

Comment: @Nandhakishore: the positive charge will still polarise the ball, so it will reduce the density of positive charge on the near side of the ball and increase the positive charge on the far side of the ball. This increases the average distance between the test charge and the charges on the ball, so it will decrease the force.

Answer (score 0):

A test charge is an idealization - an infinitesimally small charge. A real charge causes redistribution of charge on the metal ball, so more negative charge moves closer to the external positive charge, so the measured force becomes greater than it would be if the charge were not redistributed, and it is the non-redistributed charge that determines the initial electric field of the metal ball.

Comment: If the magnitude of the test charge is infinitesimally small, won't the electric field be infinity?

Comment: And whats the case for two like charges?